# How to fix Module Import Error with speech_recognition?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm currently trying to make some code that will listen to what you say, and then translate that into morse code.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import playsound
from gtts import gTTS
import os

num = 1


def assistant_speaks(output):
    global num 

    # num to rename every audio file 
    # with different name to remove ambiguity 
    num += 1
    print("BRO : ", output)

    toSpeak = gTTS(text = output, lang ='en-uk', slow = False)
    # saving the audio file given by google text to speech
    file = str(num)+".mp3 "
    toSpeak.save(file)

    playsound.playsound(file, True)

    os.remove(file)



def get_audio():
    rObject = sr.Recognizer()
    audio = ''

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Speak...")
    
        # recording the audio using speech recognition
        audio = rObject.listen(source, phrase_time_limit = 5)
    print("Stop.") # limit 5 secs

    try:

        text = rObject.recognize_google(audio, language ='en-US')
        print("You : ", text)
        return text

    except:
        speak = "Could not understand your audio, please try again!"
        assistant_speaks(speak, grootmode)
        return 0
```

However, Python is giving me some problems. Namely, it doesn't recognize that speech_recognition exists.

```
$ C:/Users/J/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/python.exe d:/J/Documents/p
ython_files/raspi/morse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/J/Documents/python_files/raspi/morse.py", line 1, in <module>
    import speech_recognition as sr
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

However, it does.

```
cefpython3        66.0
certifi           2020.12.5
chardet           4.0.0
click             7.1.2
gTTS              2.2.2
idna              2.10
pip               21.0.1
playsound         1.2.2
PyAudio           0.2.11
pywin32           300
requests          2.25.1
six               1.15.0
SpeechRecognition 3.8.1
urllib3           1.26.3
winspeech         1.0.1
```

As far as I can tell I only have python version 3.8.8.  I'm using Visual Studio Code for an editor, and I am using Windows 10 as my OS.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share more info?

- How did you install the python package? (pip3.8, Anaconda, ...)
- If you are using pip, can you show: `pip3.8 list`
- Are you using a virtual environment?
- According to https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/, you can do a quick test after installation. Can you try: `python3.8 -m speech_recognition`?

### Edit:

Ok, so now we know that the speech_recognition module can run under python3.8.

#### On the problem with vs code:

How are you executing the script (via the terminal by typing `python3.8 <name of your script>` or via the vs code run button)?

Assuming (yes I know it's dangerous) you installed it via [these steps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) (on the vs code website) and run it via vs code, can you show the environment?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

> Note: By default, VS Code uses the interpreter identified by python:pythonPath setting when debugging code.
>
> The Status Bar always shows the current interpreter.
>
> [image]

#### On the minimum energy threshold:

The Troubleshooting guide, on the pypi page, might give some insight:

> `recognizer_instance.energy_threshold` ... This value depends entirely on your microphone or audio data. There is no one-size-fits-all value, but good values typically range from 50 to 4000.

> ### The recognizer can’t recognize speech right after it starts listening for the first time.
>
> The recognizer_instance.energy_threshold property is probably set to a value that is too high to start off with, and then being adjusted lower automatically by dynamic energy threshold adjustment. Before it is at a good level, the energy threshold is so high that speech is just considered ambient noise.
>
> The solution is to decrease this threshold, or call recognizer_instance.adjust_for_ambient_noise beforehand, which will set the threshold to a good value automatically.

This might be difficult since the 'quick test' script does not allow for modifications. You could try taking [**main**.py](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/speech_recognition/__main__.py) from the repo and adapting it (so you can tweak the energy_threshold value).

It might also be worth to list all the microphones, to be sure you are using the correct one.

```
import speech_recognition as sr
for index, name in enumerate(sr.Microphone.list_microphone_names()):
    print("Microphone with name \"{1}\" found for `Microphone(device_index={0})`".format(index, name))
```

Comment: Thank you making me realize I didn't add enough info.  I did use pip to install it.  I'm not using a virtual environment, and when I try the command at the bottom it says this:  python3.8 -m speech_recognition
A moment of silence, please...
Set minimum energy threshold to 18030.43317333706
Say something!  And stays there even if I say some things, pause, try again.  And I tested to make sure my microphone was working beforehand.